# Installing Custom Rom on a S3 with Damaged Volume Down

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rom-flashing

Is it safe to install a custom ROM on a S3 with a non-functional volume down key?

What should I circumvent or be ware of during the install?

p.s: the key cannot be repaired.

Comment: You might be able to get it into the right mode with `adb reboot recovery` or `adb reboot bootloader`.

Comment: Additionally to `adb`, Samsung phones can be forced into 'download mode' through a **USB jig**, and therefore gets you to a state where you can flash whatever you need over Odin/Heimdal/KEIS/etc. You can purchase them [online for cheap](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR2.TRC1.A0.H0.Xsamsung+usb+jig.TRS0&_nkw=samsung+usb+jig&_sacat=0&_from=R40) or [make your own](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/need-a-samsung-usb-jig-build-your-own/). Just something to note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a volume-down key, you can't:

- go into recovery mode/download mode without a PC
- reduce the volume (duh)
- select options in CWM
- take screenshots in AOSP-based ROMs

Possible workarounds, by order of mention above:

- use `adb reboot recovery` / `adb reboot bootloader`, as said in the comments
- use a USB jig to force the phone to boot into Download Mode
- go into Settings > Sound > Volumes and change values from there
- use TWRP or CWM Touch instead
- use third-party apps. I think GravityBox for Xposed has the option to add a screenshot option and advanced reboot to the power menu, but I haven't been using Xposed for a *long* time.

Comment: Having used GravityBox for a long time, you can also enable a setting to have "Recovery" and "Bootloader" as options to reboot to; that way you don't actually need a PC. There is a Volume toggle in QS options as well.